# Stuck nut on bike axle?

Tags: road-bike, tire, wheels, maintenance, axle

I've got a bike. There is a stuck nut on the axle, and when I try twisting it.. well.. the axle turns too (obviously.). I'm trying to get it off, but it won't come off. My grandfather has a vast arrange of tools in the garage, so I have a good chance of finding any tool I need to get this pest off. WD40 is also in there. If you can help me and tell me how to get it off, please do!

Comment: Welcome, are you aware there are two nuts on each side of the hub, that are locked against each other? It's not clear to me either way from the wording. You could [edit] in a picture to illustrate the problem

Comment: If the answers so far aren't helping, please add a clear photo of each side of your wheel's hub to the question with [edit]  That will help show what we're working with.    +1 for a well-equipped workshop, that's a good start, but its tempting to move straight to the cutting tools, which shouldn't be required.

Comment: Did you get your wheel sorted @felix ?

Answer (score 4):

The first approach to take is try to immobilize the axle by getting the other side dropout extra super duper pinched between the locknut and axle nut. If that side's axle nut can be freed, remove it and grease the threads. Snake in a cone wrench and open wrench on that side if applicable and get the cone and locknut very tight against one another. Then with a wrench on the cone if possible or the locknut if not, reef down on the axle nut. You may get more preload by adding a washer if it doesn't have one, and you'll tear up the dropout less. Then try again on the stuck nut. If you can put a wrench also on that side's locknut while doing so, it will help to immobilize the axle. (If you have access and think it will work, you could also just try putting a wrench on that locknut without doing the other steps. That will be enough some amount of the time.)

This only takes a minute and usually it just works.

Depending on what locknuts you do and don't have access to, another approach can be do the above to the extent possible, then try to break free the offending side's cone and locknuts from each other, then do wrenches on that side's axle nut and locknut.

Getting penetrating oil on the stuck nut will help with any of the above.